# Magento 2 Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-Patch installation

Tags: magento2, patches, magento-2.1.7, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I need to update this patch on magento 2.1.7 - I am confused with file structure. 
CE-2.0.0 to CE-2.3.0/vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/

where should I upload these files and what is my CLI command i would need to execute this? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Refer this link https://medium.com/@LarsRoettig/how-to-apply-patches-on-magento-2-b4fd83537f61

Answer (score 0):

Now Apply Patch directly in vendor folder
This patch is applicable on all **Magento 2.x and 1.x versions**.

Alternatively you can use patched files from following address and replace them in your vendor folder.

https://github.com/MeetanshiInc/Magento-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-Patch-for-M1-M2

If Need Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;`

After apply patch you will see *Signature Key*
[image]

Comment: if I upload the files from this module to Vendor directly, it prompts me to overwrite some files, I select yes, when I do that its breaks up my site.

Comment: You need to be in developer mode, and then you need to run the SSH upgrade, static content deploy, and clear cache commands, after you replace those files. . .

Comment: This package have files with Magento version wise. please check you Magento version and files version

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the patch is poorly written. It was based on a magento 2.2 and up and for php 7.0 and higher. In my case, had lower php and magento 2.1.1, applied the patch per instruction and broke my site and had a bunch of Parse error in the code.

so I did the following and and now it is working (more tests needed...beware this was a dirty work-around):

Files to modify in location:
vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php
vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Response.php

The following code needs to be modified:
In vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php

Line 245 remove : 
`: string` 
Line 258 (change): 
`private function getSignatureKey(): string` to this----> 
`private function getSignatureKey()`

Line 271 (change) :
`private function setSignatureKey(string $signatureKey)`
to this---->`private function setSignatureKey($signatureKey)`

In vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Response.php 
Line 79 (change):
`private function generateSha2Hash(string $signatureKey): string` 
 to this----> `private function generateSha2Hash($signatureKey)`

Line 114 (change and add): 
`foreach ($hashFields as $field) {

            $message .= ($this->getData($field) ?? '') . '^';`

 TO THIS ------>

`foreach ($hashFields as $field) {
            if (!empty($this->getData($field))) {
                $message .= $this->getData($field);
            }
            $message .= '^';`

Then run compile.